# Why the word "include" is used?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Movie "[Judgg Dredd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judge_Dredd_(film))", *Judge Griffin* say this words to *Chief Justice Fargo*

> Chief Justice, the city is in chaos! For social order, we need tighter
>   reins. Incarceration hasn't worked as a deterrent.I say we expand
>   execution to **include** lesser crimes!

"we expand execution to **include** lesser crimes!" doesn't sound perfect English sentence to me.

I think correct sentence may be: "we expand execution to **reduce** the crimes!"

Comment: The original sentence (without context) means that they will now execute people for lesser crimes in addition to whatever they had been doing before. It proposes a solution to the problem raised in the sentence previous to it, so if we were to try to phrase the original differently, our alternative would need to propose an alternative, too. But what I'm more interested in is why you think the original had been incorrect. What part doesn't sound right exactly? Does it make more sense for you if we say, "Execution should be for lesser crimes, too!"

Comment: I think what might be confusing you is that **to include lesser crimes** doesn't mean "to have fewer crimes", it means "to be applied to *less serious* crimes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think correct sentence may be: "we expand execution to reduce the crimes!"

You're misunderstanding the meaning. Your confusion stems from the example that is used, so let me first explain an easier example:

> Until now, only men were allowed to vote. But from this day on, we have expanded our country's voting rights to include **women**.

Translation: women are now voters. This was not the case in the past.

> Until now, only murders were punished with execution. But from this day on we expand execution to include **robberies**!

Translation: robberies are now punishable by execution. This was not the case in the past.

> Until now, only murders were punished with execution. But from this day on we expand execution to include **lesser crimes**!

Translation: "lesser crimes" are now punishable by execution. This was not the case in the past.

"lesser crime" does not mean "less crime" (= reducing the amount of crime that happens).

"lesser crime" means "a crime that is less offensive".

For example: compared to murder, a robbery is a lesser crime, because robbing someone is not as bad as murdering someone.

I hope I explained this clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

*"I say we expand execution to **include lesser crimes**!"*
It means he wants to add more crimes to their list of "capital crimes", specifically he wants to **include crimes that are less serious** than the ones already on that list.